# How to initialize the classes in factory method which have constructors with multiple parameters

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory

Lets say I have a Shape interface which calculates the area of shape. I add 2 implementations Rectangle and Square. The challenge I see is both implementations have their own multiple argument constructors. How do I initialize them using a factory pattern.
I wanted to solve it using java.

```
public class Rectangle implements Shape {
int length;
int breadth;

public Rectangle(List<String> parameters) {
    this.length = Integer.parseInt(parameters.get(0));
    this.breadth = Integer.parseInt(parameters.get(1));
}

@Override
public int area() {
    return length * breadth;
}
```

}

```
public class Square implements Shape {
int edge;

public Square(List<String> parameters) {
    this.edge = Integer.parseInt(parameters.get(0));
}

@Override
public int area() {

    return edge * edge;
}
```

}

```
public interface Shape {
int area();
```

}

```
public interface ShapeFactory {
public Shape make(String shapeType);
public List<String> getParameters(String shapeType);
```

}

```
public class ShapeFactoryImpl implements ShapeFactory {
Map<String, List<String>> shapeInitMap = new HashMap<>();

public void init(){
    shapeInitMap.put("Circle", Arrays.asList(new String[]{"4"}));
    shapeInitMap.put("Rectangle", Arrays.asList(new String[]{"2","3"}));
}

@Override
public Shape make(String shapeType) {
    switch (shapeType) {
    case "Circle":
        return new Square(getParameters(shapeType));
    case "Square":
        return new Rectangle(getParameters(shapeType));
    default:
        break;
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public List<String> getParameters(String shapeType) {

    return shapeInitMap.get(shapeType);
}
```

}

Comment: Did you tried to solve it before posting the question? Where are your attempts?

Comment: yes.. able to do it when there is no argument constructor.

Comment: will upload the attempt

Comment: If these have distinct argument types, the single valid approach is defining two factory methods : one for creating Circle and another for creating Square.

Comment: Uploaded the code writtern so far. In the ShapeFactoryImpl, I am passing a list of strings to the class constructors such as Circle(getParameters(shapeType)). Is there a better way than this

Comment: To start, I would recommend asking yourself why do you want to have a factory at all? Would it simplify your code to eliminate it? What is the goal of adding a factory?

Comment: My goal here is to invert the dependency. I had a scenario where the API ie ShapeFactory does not know anything about ShapefactoryImpl and I wanted to instantiate the implementations without letting the High level module ie ShapeFactory know anything about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is not optimal, because: 1) you have to create dedicated constructors for your concrete `Shape`s and you loose the type check (at compile time) of the parameters. 2) The `init` method of the concrete factory is error prone.

Here's what I would do. The concrete factory should carry the parameters of the concrete `Shape`s constructors, but not as indetermined strings (if you get strings from user input, convert them before the creation of the concrete factory):

```
public interface ShapeFactory {
    public Shape make(String shapeType);
}

public class ShapeFactoryImpl implements ShapeFactory {
    private int circleRadius;
    private int rectangleLength;
    private int rectangleBreadth;

    public ShapeFactoryImpl(int circleRadius, int rectangleLength, int rectangleBreadth){
        this.circleRadius = circleRadius;
        this.rectangleLength = rectangleLength;
        this.rectangleBreadth = rectangleBreadth;
    }

    public Shape make(String shapeType) {
        switch (shapeType) {
            case "Circle": return new Circle(this.circleRadius); 
            case "Rectangle": return new Rectangle(this.rectangleLength, this.rectangleBreadth);
            default: throw new Exception("..."); 
        }
    }
}
```

The client does not need to know the concrete `ShapeFactory` he is using, nor has to worry about the concrete `Shape` he gets. The dependency is inverted: abstractions, not details, play the key role. But if the number of possible shapes increases, you'll get a constructor with a lot of similar parameters. Here's another solution:

```
public class ShapeFactoryImpl implements ShapeFactory {
    private Shape circle;
    private Shape rectangle;

    public ShapeFactoryImpl(Circle circle, Rectangle rectangle){
        this.circle = circle;
        this.rectangle = rectangle;
    }

    public Shape make(String shapeType) {
        switch (shapeType) {
            case "Circle": return this.circle.clone(); 
            case "Rectangle": return this.rectangle.clone();
            default: throw new Exception("..."); 
        }
    }
}
```

This is better, because you won't mix parameters: each concrete `Shape` contains its own parameters. If you want to make it more flexible, you can use a Map to move the reponsibility for the switch out of the concrete factory:

```
public class ShapeFactoryImpl implements ShapeFactory {
    private Map<String, Shape> shapeByType;

    public ShapeFactoryImpl(Map<String, Shape> shapeByType){
        this.shapeByType = shapeByType;
    }

    public Shape make(String shapeType) {
        Shape shape = this.shapeByType.get(Type).clone();
        if (shape == null) {
            throw new Exception("...");
        }
        return shape;
    }
}
```

I would even use an `enum` for shape types instead of a string, and an `EnumMap` to handle the switch:

```
public class ShapeFactoryImpl implements ShapeFactory {
    private EnumMap<ShapeType, Shape> shapeByType;

    public ShapeFactoryImpl(Map<ShapeType, Shape> shapeByType){
        this.shapeByType = shapeByType;
    }

    public Shape make(ShapeType shapeType) {
        return this.shapeByType.get(Type).clone();
    }
}
```

The client has to know the `Shape` and `ShapeFactory` interface and the `ShapeType` enum. The "server" provides the concrete `ShapeFactoryImpl` instance.